# Python - subprocess command with pipe which also writes to a file

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess, pipe

I want run a batch script on windows through python subprocess.call with piple. I have the below list which contains the batch script with all its arguments.

```
  process_list [ 'batch_script.bat', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3' ]
```

Now I want to grep few specific line using below pipe and grep command

```
above command|grep -iE 'abc|xyz'
```

Now I also want to write it to a file or store into a variable, I tried to find some solutions like `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`

```
pipe_var= ' | grep -iE \'abc|xyz\''
process_list.append(pipe_var)
subprocess.call(process_list, stdout=fo, shell=True) or this one
subprocess.call(process_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

but it is matching my requirement. Could you please help?

Comment: I wouldn't use `grep` but python native regex match for this (you could avoid the `|` and `shel==True` then

Comment: You should not be using an args list with `shell=True` because subprocess doesn't know how to build a shell command line from a list on Windows (on Unix it's even more wrong, for a different reason). Also, the "|" character in the grep expression needs to be escape with double quotes. This might work: `cmd = 'batch_script.bat "arg1" "arg2" "arg3" | grep -iE "abc|xyz"'`. Then use a pipe for stdout, read it and do whatever you want with the output, including writing it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [redirect stdout function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)

Something close to this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'w')
print 'this will now goto file.txt'
```